# How to change slider in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

How to set the slider of an object QVBoxLayout to the end?
I want the initial position to be like in the picture, but the slider is at the top.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QVBoxLayout* lay = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(QString(i + '0'));
        lay->addWidget(button);
    }
    ui->scrollContents->setLayout(lay);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
auto bar = scrollableArea->verticalScrollBar();
bar->setValue(bar->maximum());
```

Comment: should i add something to the class QtScrollArea? When I change in this way for a regular object QtScrollBar, then everything works, but when I change it for a class field, then it doesn’t